# Ignoring a hidden field on event registration form

Tags: civievent, custom-templates

I have a custom event template on which I hide some fields based on whether someone is registering themselves or an additional participant. There are 2 different price options, one for the main registrant and one for the additional participant. The price set needs to have required fields for each situation. How can I get civi to ignore the required fields if they are hidden?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this cannot be controlled in CiviCRM ATM. However there is an [extension](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond)(from Allen Shaw) for conditional filtering on profile but I guess this will not work in your case.

I would suggest you to create an extension and use combination of [buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) or [ValidateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) hook to achieve.

Cheers

Pradeep